# different result for left join vs update a table with another table

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables, `tableGeneral` and `tableRef`. First I made a new `table1` from `tableGeneral` and did a left join with `tableRef` when the `spec` fields were the same. Then I counted the `pk_num` which was added after joining and it was 9200 records. 
Second, I created a `table2` from `tableGenral`. Then, I added a column and made an update on `table2` with a subquery by selecting `pk_num` where the spec was the same as in `table2`. This resulted in 6900 records after counting `f_num`!
I did a `count(distinct(...))` for both.

p.s. Moreover, the `pk_num` is unique and using `min` in the subquery was just because of the duplicated rows with the same `pk_num`. So, it does not an effect on the result.
p.s. my tables are not small enough to be included here.

first query:

```
create table table1 as
(
select a.ID, a.spec, b.pk_num from tableGeneral a
left join tableRef b
on upper(a.spec)=upper(b.spec)
group by a.ID, a.spec, b.pk_num);
```

second query:

```
create table table2 as
(
select ID, spec
from tableGeneral
);

alter table table2
add f_num VARCHAR(100); 

update table2 a
set f_num=null;

update  table2 a
set a.f_num=(select /*+parallel(12)*/ min(b.pk_num)
from tableRef b
where upper(a.spec)=upper(b.spec));
```

I think that they should show the same result when I count but they didn't and I cannot understand why this happened! whould you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

They will not show the same count if you have duplicates in `TableRef`.  You can check for this:

```
select upper(r.spec)
from tableref r
group by upper(r.spec)
having count(distinct r.pk_num) > 1;
```

Why?  In your first query you are including `pk` in the `GROUP BY`, so duplicates are not being removed by the aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
You mean that ```count(distinct(pk_num))``` for the first and ```count(distinct(f_num))``` for the second one should not show the same result? using distinct doesn't cause to omit duplication?

Comment: @Adroit . . . I sort of assumed that `pk_num` is unique, but yes, formally, it would be `count(distinct pk_num)`.  `f_num` is not relevant to this; it is in `table_a`.

Comment: @Adroit . . . There are duplicate `r_spec`s.

Comment: but actually ```f_num``` from ```table2``` should be the same as ```pk_num``` in ```table1```. shouldn't be?!

Answer (score 0):

If your tableGeneral has several "spec"s for different IDs, table2 will naturally have less rows than table1, as table2 is taking the MIN(PK_NUM) for each unique spec, and table1 is taking every single PK_NUM for every single existing spec, so it will probably create some duplicates

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But both ```spec``` and ```pk_num``` are unique. There are some case that some rows duplicated but all have the same relation for ```spec``` and ```pk_num```.